# Функция, отвечающая за изменение размера окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Есть блок, размеры которого указаны в %. Нужна функция, отвечающая за изменение размров последнего. Тоесть при изменении размеров окна.

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Я, думаю, здесь вопрос в том, что нужно получать размеры какого-то блока (каким-нибудь getcomputedstyle или innerWidth), который будет слушаться resize'ом... но это неточно (с)

Comment: Да. Именно это имеется введу

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
  console.log($('#block').width());
})
```

```css
#block{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#cda;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
```